# Growing a struct with GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, struct

I've been working on a little custom made database in MATLAB.

I have a GUI with a bunch of 'Edit Text' boxes and buttons.

The key  is that I should be able to register an undefined number of students with some information like names, surnames, code etc. I've managed to store only one student (i.e the first time i push the 'Submit Button') but when i enter another student's information, MATLAB just overwrites the information from the previous registration.

Here's the Callback for the 'Submit' button

```
function Submit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global n 
n=n+1

% hObject    handle to Submit (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

name1 = get(handles.name,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
name2=get(handles.name2,'String');
name3=get(handles.name3,'String');
major=get(handles.major,'String');
labavg=num2str(get(handles.labavg,'String'));
finalgrade=num2str(get(handles.finalgrade,'String'));
email=num2str(get(handles.email,'String'));
code=num2str(get(handles.code,'String'));

for ii=1:numel(n)
    student_information(ii).name=name1
    student_information(ii).surname1=name2
    student_information(ii).surname2=name3
    student_information(ii).code=code
    student_information(ii).major=major
    student_information(ii).final_grade=finalgrade
    student_information(ii).laboratory_average=labavg
    student_information(ii).email=email
end
assignin('base', 'student_information', student_information)
end
```

I've declared the counter 'n' as a global variable set to '0' in the workspace.
I'm not sure if my code isn't looping properly. Maybe the mistake is in there but I can't see how to fix it.
Can you please help me with my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with your loop, but I don't see the need for it. Also, by using `assignin`, you are overriding the contents of `student_information` in your workspace. You are better off making `student_information` global in `Submit_Callback` in addition to `n`, then construct a `new_student` structure using your information and append it to `student_information` as follows:

```
name1 = get(handles.name,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
name2=get(handles.name2,'String');
name3=get(handles.name3,'String');
major=get(handles.major,'String');
labavg=num2str(get(handles.labavg,'String'));
finalgrade=num2str(get(handles.finalgrade,'String'));
email=num2str(get(handles.email,'String'));
code=num2str(get(handles.code,'String'));

new_student.name = name1;
new_student.surname1 = name2;
new_student.surname2 = name3;
new_student.major = major;
new_student.laboratory_average = labavg;
new_student.final_grade = finalgrade;
new_student.email = email;
new_student.code = code;

student_information(n) = new_student;
n = n + 1;
```

and that should append the new entry at the end of the struct array.

Comment: Ok. I've modified my code and it seems to work but i can't see the struct growing...Now, if I want to see and save the student_information on the workspace I made student_information global in save_Callback but as before, the struct appears with only one student even when if I submit more than one student:

    function save_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    global  student_information
    assignin('base', 'student_information', student_information)

Comment: Are you sure the code is being reached? If you have a `student_information`variable in your workspace and declare it global in your function, it should grow. Is it overriding the previous information? What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: You were right. student_information wasn't declared as global in the workspace. Now it grows but it starts from row 2.

Comment: Ah - I edited my answer. You should use `n` then. Keep that global definition, and increment it either before (as in your example) or after as in mine. That should sort it out.

Comment: You solved it. Maybe it was simple but I was really having a bad time with this. I really appreciate the time you spent helping me. Thanks!